# Sum of diagonal blocks of inverse of block matrix

Tags: matrices, inverse, symmetric-matrices, positive-semidefinite, block-matrices

I have an $(kn \times kn)$ dimensional square positive semi-definite symmetric matrix of the form:

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}A_{11} & A_{21} & ... & A_{n1} \\ A_{21}' & A_{22} & ... & A_{n2} \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ A_{n1}' & A_{n2}' & ... & A_{nn} \\ \end{bmatrix}$$

Where the blocks, $\{A_{ij}\}_{i, j\in \{1,...n\}}$, are square and of dimension $(k \times k)$. Denote the inverse of $A$ as $B$, so that $B^{-1}=A$ and partition $B$ as:

$$B=\begin{bmatrix}B_{11} & B_{21} & ... & B_{n1} \\ B_{21}' & B_{22} & ... & B_{n2} \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ B_{n1}' & B_{n2}' & ... & B_{nn} \\ \end{bmatrix}$$

Where the blocks, $\{B_{ij}\}_{i, j\in \{1,...n\}}$, are also square and of dimension $(k \times k)$. I want to find the sum of the diagonal blocks of $B$ in terms of the original blocks of $A$. That is, I want to find:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n B_{ii}$$

In terms of the $\{A_{ij}\}_{i,j \in \{1,...,n\}}$. Does anyone know of any nice formulae for this?

Comment: $'$ is transpose

Comment: Apologies I'm not sure I understand - What do you mean?

Comment: $A_{21}$ should be $A_{12}$.

Comment: You forgot to mention that the diagonal blocks are symmetric.

Comment: There's a transpose on $A_{21}$. The diagonal blocks being symmetric also follows from me saying $A$ is symmetric no?

Comment: The transposition should be on the blocks above the diagonal then.

Comment: Why do you say this?

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1946713/339790)'s how "ugly" it looks for the $2 \times 2$ case. You could use some form of recursion to find the inverse in terms of the inverse of the northwest block. If you want a formula for, say, $n=10$, you might need a few pages to write it down. Things can get [funny](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2086542/339790).

Answer (score 0):

For $k=1$ , As, $B=A^{-1}$, by the rule of trace of matrix, $\sum_{i=1}^n B_{ii} = \text{sum of all reciprocals of all eigenvalues of A} = (-1)^{n-1}  \frac{\text{sum of all minors of A of order (n-1)}}{|A|} $

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Apologies I think maybe my question was not clear enough/misleading - the $B_{ij}$ are block partitions, not elements. I will rephrase to make this clear.

Comment: @A learner, were you suggesting there is a more general result?